# Partial Function Eta Equivalence

Tags: dafny

I am wondering if `f:T~>S` (a partial function that may read heap objects) is equalivalent to `(x:T) reads f.reads requires f.requires(x) f(x)` in Dafny. This should be true, if they are total functions, they are eta-equivalence. For partial functions, I would expect they are equivalent as well, as they have the same requirements and whenever the input is in the domain, their outputs are equivalent.

However, when I have partial functions in `seq`, they seem to be treated differently. As we can see from the answer of [Prove theorem about seq(i,f)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77618089/prove-theorem-about-seqi-f). Having the expanded version works,

```
lemma seq_thm<T>(j:nat,f:nat ~> T)
requires forall i :: 0 <= i < j ==> f.requires(i)
ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < j ==>
  seq(j,(n:nat) reads f.reads requires f.requires(n) => f(n))[i] == f(i)
{
}
```

while the eta reduced form does not.

```
lemma seq_thm<T>(j:nat,f:nat ~> T)
requires forall i :: 0 <= i < j ==> f.requires(i)
ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < j ==> seq(j,f)[i] == f(i)
{
}
```

Are the two form equivalent in Dafny? If so, how can we convince Dafny they are equivalent? If not, why?
I have tried to make a theorem to state the two forms are equivalent, but I couldn't prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at boogie code generated by Dafny in above case. First let's take look at axiom of [Seq#Create](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/blob/master/Source/DafnyCore/DafnyPrelude.bpl#L1006)

```
axiom (forall ty: Ty, heap: Heap, len: int, init: HandleType, i: int ::
  { Seq#Index(Seq#Create(ty, heap, len, init), i) }
  $IsGoodHeap(heap) && 0 <= i && i < len ==>
  Seq#Index(Seq#Create(ty, heap, len, init), i) == Apply1(TInt, ty, heap, init, $Box(i)));
```

Next look at postcondition generated in boogie

```
  ensures (forall i#3: int :: 
    { Apply1(Tclass._System.nat(), _module._default.seq_thm$T, $Heap, f#0, $Box(i#3)) } 
      { Seq#Index(Seq#Create(_module._default.seq_thm$T, $Heap, j#0, f#0), i#3) } 
    true
       ==> 
      LitInt(0) <= i#3 && i#3 < j#0
       ==> Seq#Index(Seq#Create(_module._default.seq_thm$T, $Heap, j#0, f#0), i#3)
         == Apply1(Tclass._System.nat(), _module._default.seq_thm$T, $Heap, f#0, $Box(i#3)));
```

Well axiom matches part we have to prove except `TTint` does n't match `Tclass._System.nat()`.

I modifies code to below and voila it verifies

```
lemma seq_thm <T> (j: nat, f: int --> T)
  requires forall i :: 0 <= i < j ==> f.requires(i)
  ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < j ==> seq(j, f)[i] == f(i)
{}
```

Comment: I have filed an issue on dafny repo https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/4901

Comment: Meanwhile here's a work around that transform `nat --> T` to `int --> T`.

`function to_int_func<T>(f:nat ~> T): int ~> T
{
  (n: int) reads f.reads requires n > 0 && f.requires(n) => f(n)
}`