Generic Seq Comprehension in Dafny
I'm unable to prove the following basic property of a sequence comprehension.
  lemma LemmaSeqComprehension<T>(n: nat, fn: nat --> T, index: nat)
    requires forall i: nat :: i < n ==> fn.requires(i)
    requires index < n
    ensures seq(n, fn)[index] == fn(index)
  {
  }

What am I missing?
Update:
Interestingly I can get it working with:
lemma LemmaSeqComprehension<T>(n: nat, fn: nat --> T, index: nat)
    requires forall i: nat :: i < n ==> fn.requires(i)
    requires index < n
    ensures
      var fn_copy := (i: nat) requires i < n => fn(i);
      seq(n, fn_copy)[index] == fn(index)
  {
  }

which is a reasonable workaround.
Final Update:
I ended up replacing where I had been using the sequence comprehension with a custom recursive function which made everything much easier, and I no longer need this lemma.
(All with dafny version 4.6.0.0)

I believe you were running into this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77667748/partial-function-eta-equivalence
